# Mostrar erro específico no ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Criei um site que funciona normalmente, porém, ao upá-lo no servidor de hospedagem, ele mostra um erro:

> Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.

Como o erro é muito genérico, ele diz pra incluir a linha `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` no meu arquivo `web.config`. Fiz isso, mas o erro retornado é?

> An error occurred while processing your request.

Ou seja, nenhum dos erros ajuda muito.

Quero saber como ver uma mensagem mais específica de erro pra facilitar a correção.

No meu caso, o erro ocorre quando tento criar um arquivo *txt* e fazer o download (deve ser erro de permissão). Como posso saber se é isso mesmo e corrigir?

Comment: Provavelmente o código está impedindo mostrar o erro. As pessoas acham que capturar uma exceção é algo bom, mas em geral é o que causa mais problema. Veja também se está configurando certo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4364032/221800

Comment: Fiz a configuração que passaram no link e deu erro: 500 - Erro de servidor interno.

Comment: Agora apareceu: Método não-estático requer um destino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente o erro era que tinha mais de um `<system.web>`, só pode ter um, ou a configuração do erro não estava dentro desta seção. Pode ser interessante ligar o modo de depuração também.

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/DebugMode.xml).

Certifique-se também que não há nenhuma captura de exceção que impede do erro ser mostrado.

Comment: consegui ver o erro, vou criar outra pergunta pra tentar resolve-lo